# Incorrect Visualization of Geojson using Vue2-Leaflet

Tags: vuejs2, leaflet, geojson

I'm having a problem when visualizing my `GeoJSON` files on the web using `Vue2Leaflet`. 
The user uploads files in the form of `.dxf`, then the `Django` backend process it into various layers and send it back to the front end. I received all the layers in the form of `GeoJSON` object, and I use `l-map` of `Vue2Leaflet` to visualize whichever layer is selected.

Could you please tell me what's happening here? The same code works perfectly with the example API given by the developer themselves, but not with my `GeoJSON`.

[Reference Example](https://korigan.github.io/Vue2Leaflet/examples/#)

Note: My `GeoJSON` if visualized in `QGIS` shows a map shape, or at least not such a straight line for the layer.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please share your code and a sample of the GeoJSON data - it's pretty much impossible to help you otherwise.

Comment: @peeebeee here is the detail of my issue in github:
> https://github.com/vue-leaflet/Vue2Leaflet/issues/478